# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375 on windows wsl

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am getting the below error when trying to use docker in Windows WSL Ubuntu on a Windows 10 Home Basic
[Image for the error, URL may not be localhost because was trying something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz7ij.png)

```
root@LAPTOP-F9O4PA9U:/home/jeethesh# docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I am using Docker Toolbox on Windows as it doesn't support Docker Desktop on Windows 10 Home Basic.

Please let me know if anyone has any solution for this or if you require any more details